# Why isn't the https.request callback called?

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, https, jasny-bootstrap

I have some node.js code where I'm trying to get package.info from raw.github.com. I'm doing a HTTPS request, but for some reason it looks like the callback is never called, because 'here' is never outputted.

Does anyone see what's going wrong?

```
console.log(options)

req = https.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('here')
  res.setEncoding('utf8')
  // ... more code here
 })

 console.log(req)

 // .. return -> listening and waiting
```

Output

```
{ host: 'raw.github.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/jasny/bootstrap/2.2.2-j3-wip/package.json',
  method: 'GET' }
{ domain: null,
  _events:
   { response: { [Function: g] listener: [Function] },
     socket: { [Function: g] listener: [Function] } },
  _maxListeners: 10,
  output: [],
  outputEncodings: [],
  writable: true,
  _last: false,
  chunkedEncoding: false,
  shouldKeepAlive: true,
  useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
  sendDate: false,
  _hasBody: true,
  _trailer: '',
  finished: false,
  agent:
   { domain: null,
     _events: { free: [Function] },
     _maxListeners: 10,
     options: {},
     requests: {},
     sockets: { 'raw.github.com:443': [Object] },
     maxSockets: 5,
     createConnection: [Function: createConnection] },
  socketPath: undefined,
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/jasny/bootstrap/2.2.2-j3-wip/package.json',
  _headers: { host: 'raw.github.com' },
  _headerNames: { host: 'Host' }
}
```

For the full code see [lib/packageinfo.js](https://github.com/jasny/bootstrap-server/blob/wip/lib/packageinfo.js). The function is called in [index.js](https://github.com/jasny/bootstrap-server/blob/wip/index.js)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call `end()` on the request to execute it, like this:

```
req = https.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('here')
  res.setEncoding('utf8')
  // ... more code here
});
req.end();   // <= Here
```